# Who taught the Vedas and scriptures to Bhishma?

Tags: bhishma, mahabharata

After war, Yudhisthira goes to Bhishma and Bhishma educates him further on duties of a king, Vedas, Shastras, scriptures and statecraft. Bhishma was taught the skills of warfare by Parshuram but who taught the Vedas and scriptures to Bhishma?

Comment: Devaguru Brihaspati...

Comment: please answer in answer section and that too with evidence

Answer (score 3):

Sage Vasishtha taught the Vedas to Gangadatta/Devavrata (Bhisma).

As per Goddess Ganga, Devavrata was master in all the Sashtras which were known to both Usanas (Asuras' guru) and Vrihaspati (Devas' guru) though no clear indication if they taught him.

> And Ganga said, 'O tiger among men, that eighth son whom thou hadst some time before begat upon me is this. Know that this excellent child is conversant with all weapons, O monarch, take him now. I have reared him with care. And go home, O tiger among men, taking him with thee. Endued with superior intelligence, **he has studied with Vasishtha the entire Vedas with their branches**. Skilled in all weapons and a mighty bowman, he is like Indra in battle. And, O Bharata, both the gods and the Asuras look upon him with favour. **Whatever branches of knowledge are known to Usanas, this one knoweth completely**. And so is **he the master of all those Sastras that the son of Angiras (Vrihaspati)** adored by the gods and the Asuras, knoweth. And **all the weapons known to the powerful and invincible Rama, the son of Jamadagni are known to this thy illustrious son of mighty arms**. O king of superior courage, take this thy own heroic child given unto thee by me. He is a mighty bowman and conversant with the interpretation of all treatises on the duties of a king.' ~ [Sambhava Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01101.htm)